# how to get only url links from users and make them valid url form

Tags: javascript, url

I am a total beginner at Javascript and HTML5, so I am not sure I am properly asking these questions.

I want to get only links from users on my page and turn them into url links. Two questions are there.

Is it possible to make sure whether users only input url links and make them work as url link forms properly?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between users links to url links?

Comment: I think :  user write url string in input and he want to convert into `<a>` element

Comment: Yes Alexis! That was what I wanted to know!.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

**Example with Jquery**

```js
$("#btnurl").click(function(){
  if($("#url").val()!="")
  {
    $(".render").append("<a href='"+$("#url").val()+"'>"+$("#url").val()+"</a>");
  }
  else
    alert("You must paste an url before");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input placeholder="Paste your url" id="url" type="text"> <button type="button" id="btnurl">Go URL</button>

<div class="render"></div>
```

Comment: @HosungKo You're welcome ! don't forget to validate for other people ;D